# How to drag an image with JavaScript Canvas api and add a label to it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this code

```
<canvas id="Con1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

var Rxt = document.getElementById('Con1').getContext('2d');
Rxt.fillStyle = 'green';
Rxt.fillRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
Rxt.rotate(.2);

var Img = document.createElement('img');
Img.src = 'images/009-Invoice1-A4-SET-PAD.png';
Img.onload = function () {
    Rxt.drawImage(Img, 50, 0, 200, 200); 
}

var down = false;

Rxt.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    down = true;
}, false);

Rxt.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    down = false;
}, false);

Rxt.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (down) {
         Rxt.translate(0, -50);

         Rxt.drawImage(Img, event.clientX - this.offsetLeft,

         event.clientY - this.offsetTop, 100, 100);

         Rxt.translate(0, 50);

    }
}, false);

</script>
```

I've tried this and I'm adding an image on the canvas and dragging it. It works but the image is dragging continuously and it prints duplicate images but the output should be smooth. I also want to add a label to that image and have it moveable.

Comment: Hi still no one replying but you are giving -1 why?did i ask any wrong question...many times i aske specific question but no reply from your side..if you dont know answer means you will put -1 ?

Comment: Your question just looks like "paste code and ask for help" question a lot of people don't bother reading questions like that. I'm working on your exact solution but by the sounds of your description you might just need to clear your canvas before you draw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the canvas each time you want to draw something and redraw everything.
I'd also suggest that you look up canvas context `.restore()` and `.save()` as they are very useful when dealing with canvas transformations

As for the label you'd probably have to use the `fillText` or `stokeText` methods

See if this helps at all
http://pastebin.com/kuaTbuhW

Comment: is it possible to move text on over canvas instade of image?

Comment: The  fillText and strokeText methods take coordinates so anythings possible

Comment: hi i have two working code please can you merge it and give me?